# How do I verify my cf app configuration items

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm just starting to play with the IBM cloud offering. I've built a simple flask app and am trying to deployt it via a toolchain. When I run my toolchain the app deploys successfully, however I can't access the url.

I am looking at the deployment logs and have a couple of questions.

First, I see this:

`2020-12-24T15:00:39.66+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  * Environment: production`

But the environment I thought I was deploying to was dev. How do I change the environment I expect the toolchain to deploy to?

I'm assuming that the url that shows up in the log output should be accessible, but it isn't.

My manifest has `random-route: true` defined. How do I check that the url in the logs is available and pointing to my deployed cf app??

Thanks for any help and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the app using the cloud console ui at https://cloud.ibm.com  There should be a link to the app url.

It is possible to differentiate between def and prod via environment variables.  I believe you can pass environment variables via the manifest file.   You can sent via ibmcloud cf set-env and then ibmcloud cf restage.

Comment: When I click the app link url it doesn't work, I get a 404. That's ultimately what I am trying to overcome. However, I've only been using teh IBM could interface for a few days so just finding my way.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason my app was failing was I was missing a couple of items/components

First, from the code I needed these lines in my python.

`port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

The cloud foundry deployment maps the external facing url to your app.

In order to do that it needs to know what port to use and that first snippet sets it to the port defined as an environment variable (IBM Cloud defines this) or port 5000 if the variable is not set.

The second snippet is the standard script special variable evaluation and execution control mechanism.

I didn't have this or the app.run call.

adding these allowed me to get the app running by pushing it from my machine locally. Now that i have it deploying successfully, I'll start working on getting it to deploy via a toolchain.

I figured all of this out by reviewing this tutorial I found on github and comparing what they were doing and what I was doing.

https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/get-started-python

Lastly, to see how the app has been mapped go the cloud foundry section of the ui and select the app. From there you can look at the logs and they show how the app maps in the url resource access history. That being said, fundamentally this wasn't going to help me solve my problem as it was related to my source code, not the actual route mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your toolchain has environment variable set which you can change by setting the following:

```
ibmcloud cf env-set flask_app Environment development
```

It can also be set via mainfest.yml file as shown below:

```
env:
  env_name: development
```

URL is given on the UI that you may refer. Other way to check the URL is to look for the **route** so you may use

```
ibmcloud cf app flask_app
```

If you see any issues in accessing the app using route so it means there is some problem with the app causing this to happen.